# Spring Environment Variables on Linux

Tags: java, linux, spring

I've a java web-app with JSF 2.2 and Spring 4.2.
My goal is to deploy my web-app on glassfish 4.1.1, and the OS is ubuntu server 16.04.

I try to deploy my web-app with the following command

```
asadmin deploy myWebApp.war
```

but after I fill userName and password I've an error that tell me my application doesn't see an environment variable.

The configuration that generates the error is the following

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Bean
public PropertiesFactoryBean myExternalProperties() {
    PropertiesFactoryBean res = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    res.setFileEncoding("UTF-8");
    res.setLocation(new FileSystemResource(env.resolvePlaceholders("${MY_ENV_VAR}") + "external.properties"));
    return res;
}
```

but if from the command line I launch the following command

```
printenv MY_ENV_VAR
```

the variable is correctly filled.

I've tried in two different ways

1. Place the environment variable in /home/myUser/.bashrc adding the line export MY_ENV_VAR=myPath
2. Place the environment variable in /etc/profile.d/myShFile.sh adding the line export MY_ENV_VAR=myPath

But no luck. Can you help me?
On Windows the application is working, I suppose I'm doing something wrong while setting the environment variable.

Comment: Please add the error log.

Comment: A problem occurred whilst attempting to access the property 'myExternalProperties': 'Error creating bean with name 'myExternalProperties' defined in com.myapp.conf.AppSpringConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${MY_ENV_VAR}external.properties (File o directory non esistente)'. Please see server.log for more details.
Command deploy failed.

Comment: the file name appears ${MY_ENV_VAR}external.properties in the log ? I asked this because I think that you're probably missing one '/' at the end of the directory path.

Comment: I confirm you, my path ends with a slash so if I would able to replace my env var the result will be something like /home/user/props/external.properties

Comment: The user that start the application server can read the property file ?

Comment: The application server automatically starts during the boot phase. In order to start I've added a file named "glassfish" in the path /etc/init.d

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115152/discussion-between-reos-and-gavi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved placing the following string

```
MY_ENV_VAR = myValue
```

in the /etc/environment file

Answer (score 0):

This could be wrong but worth a try. 
My understanding is once a linux process starts it can't read newly defined or updated environment variables. 
Thus a restart of the server should resolve your issue.